# File shredding (secure deletion) algorithm

Tags: python, file, file-system

Does anyone see anything wrong with this? I was considering using something like `srm` or `wipe` and use `os.system` to call it from Python code. Should I do that?

My main concern is drives and filesystems that use wear leveling. But even if the program overwrites a portion of the file that should render it useless right? And with the file renamed, there should be no way to tell what the file was.

```
import random
import os

def wipe(f, passes=30):
    if not os.path.isfile(f):
        return "Could not find the specified file!"
    with open(f, "ba+") as f2w:
        size = f2w.tell()
        for i in range(passes):
            f2w.seek(0)

            f2w.write(os.urandom(size))
    new_name = str(random.randint(1000,1000000000000))
    os.rename(f, new_name)
    os.remove(new_name)
    return "Success!"
```